# fullpage.js scrolling the sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Just starting to use fullPage.js. 
I wrote some sliders in my practise, and found that the slider scrolling could not be controlled by the mouse scroll-wheel. Read the help doc (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js), but still not found any params could help.
so could anyone give me some suggestions about how to solve this?

code:

```
 $(function () {
  $("#dowebok").fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,
    anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
    navigation: true,
    navigationTooltips: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
  });
});
```

problem solved,here's the code:

```
 $('.slider-section').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      if (!$('.first-slide').hasClass('active')) {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
      } else {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
      }
    } else {
      if (!$('.last-slide').hasClass('active')) {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
      } else {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.slider-section').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0){
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();   
    }else{
         $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
    }
    return false;
});
```

It works in chrome in order to work in other browser you need to disable fullpage.js scrolling

```
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
```

But you cant set it inside `afterLeave` or `onLoad` events but it is a starting point for you how you can do it.

Comment: well, now a new problem occured, it blocked at the slider-section, scrolling would not move up/down to another section

Comment: I gave a start point, you can deteminate eg
$('.last-slide').hasClass('.active'){
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
}